Eliminar ultimo carácter de un Stringvar() tkinter
Estoy tratando de construir mi primer proyecto en tkinter, el cual es una calculadora. Pero al momento de intentar construir el boton de borrar (el que elimina el ultimo carácter, no todo) no puedo encontrar una forma de poder hacerlo ya que no puedo usar .replace ni usarlo como una lista. alguna idea?
Lugar donde tengo problema:
def delcaracter():
    auxiliar = textopantalla[0, len(textopantalla)]

botondel = Button(
    frame, bg="#3A3A3B", fg="white", text="DEL", bd=4, relief="solid", width=4, height=2
)
botondel.grid(row=2, column=4)

Parte del codigo para el que le interese:
    from tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
frame = Frame(raiz, bg="black")
frame.pack()

##---------------------PANTALLA---------------------##
textopantalla = StringVar()

pantalla = Entry(frame)
pantalla.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, columnspan=5)
pantalla.config(
    bg="black",
    fg="#0576AF",
    justify="right",
    relief="raised",
    bd=5,
    textvariable=textopantalla,
    width=30,
)


def apretarboton(num):
    textopantalla.set(textopantalla.get() + num)


def deltotal():
    textopantalla.set("")


def delcaracter():
    auxiliar = textopantalla[0, len(textopantalla)]


##---------------------FILA 1---------------------##
boton7 = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="7",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=lambda: apretarboton("7"),
)
boton7.grid(row=1, column=0)
boton8 = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="8",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=lambda: apretarboton("8"),
)
boton8.grid(row=1, column=1)
boton9 = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="9",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=lambda: apretarboton("9"),
)
boton9.grid(row=1, column=2)
botondiv = Button(
    frame, bg="#3A3A3B", fg="white", text="%", bd=4, relief="solid", width=4, height=2
)
botondiv.grid(row=1, column=3)
botondelcompl = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="C",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=deltotal(),
)
botondelcompl.grid(row=1, column=4)
##---------------------FILA 2---------------------##
boton4 = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="4",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=lambda: apretarboton("4"),
)
boton4.grid(row=2, column=0)
boton5 = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="5",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=lambda: apretarboton("5"),
)
boton5.grid(row=2, column=1)
boton6 = Button(
    frame,
    bg="#3A3A3B",
    fg="white",
    text="6",
    bd=4,
    relief="solid",
    width=4,
    height=2,
    command=lambda: apretarboton("6"),
)
boton6.grid(row=2, column=2)
botonmult = Button(
    frame, bg="#3A3A3B", fg="white", text="X", bd=4, relief="solid", width=4, height=2
)
botonmult.grid(row=2, column=3)
botondel = Button(
    frame, bg="#3A3A3B", fg="white", text="DEL", bd=4, relief="solid", width=4, height=2
)
botondel.grid(row=2, column=4)

Como podrán ver en la función delcaracter() estaba tratando de crear un auxiliar que contenga todos los caracteres del texto en la pantalla menos el último para poder después usar .set() y almacenar estos mismos en la variable de la pantalla, también he probado usar .replace() pero no es posible tampoco, por lo que me quedé sin ideas.
Además de esto, cualquier sugerencia o consejo en el código es bienvenida :)

O copiaste y pegaste código sin intentar entenderlo, o no entiendo como es que en todas partes usas las StringVar() a través de sus métodos textoPantalla.get() o textoPantalla.set("") y de pronto en el método para borrar intentas saltarte dichos métodos. El error que tienes es que estás inventándote código que 4 líneas atrás escribiste correctamente. Copiar y pegar sin más no funciona para aprender (sea copiando de otros o de ti mismo). Usa los métodos get y set, y podrás hacerlo.

@Benito-B gracias, recien estoy aprendiendo hace unos dias

@DaniloSemeniuk, lo que te quisieron decir es que deberías usar text = textopantalla.get() para obtener el texto y textopantalla.set(text) para establecer en nuevo valor. Así como esta estas manejando la variable como si fuera un string y no lo es

Dicho sea de paso, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te recomiendo realizar el [tour] para que sepas como funciona la plataforma y de paso ganes tu segunda medalla. Saludos!

@Marcos Muchas gracias por tu respuesta Marcos, valoro mucho a la gente que prefiere dar una respuesta antes que descargarse con alguien que recien aprende, un abrazo!

@DaniloSemeniuk, lo mio fue solo un comentario. Si llegas a solucionar tu problema (cosa que estoy seguro de que así va a ser), podes crear una respuesta a tu propia pregunta, detallando donde estaba el error, como lo corregiste e incluyendo el código desarrollado. Tu respuesta es importante ya puede ayudar a otros. Saludos!

En mi caso me sirvió utilizar un auxiliar para almacenar el valor, editarlo, y luego reemplazar en el stringvar:
def delcaracter():
    auxiliar = textopantalla.get()
    if auxiliar:
        textopantalla.set(auxiliar[:-1])


Felicitaciones! En unas horas vas a poder marcarla como aceptada. Saludos!

Gracias por tu ayuda marcos!
